# Android - Firebase Notification open an Activity when clicked

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to open the app and show the notification data when a push notification is clicked. The code I have so far is working the only problem is that when I have two or more notifications the app shows only one ( the latest notification received) instead of showing all the single notifications in the notification view.
Also if I have more notifications received and click on it, the app loads always the first data value received.

How should I setup this properly in order to have a list of all the notifications received and when click on one of the will load the correct data?

```
private void sendNotification(String image, String title, String subtitle, String content, String url, String time, String category) {
        //RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        Intent intent = null;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        if (url.equals("")) { // Simply run your activity
            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        } else { // open a page
            if (!url.equals("")) {
                intent = new Intent(this, NewsNotificationActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", image);
                intent.putExtra("title", title);
                intent.putExtra("subtitle", subtitle);
                intent.putExtra("content", content);
                intent.putExtra("url", url);
                intent.putExtra("time", time);
                intent.putExtra("category", category);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            }
        }
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.loading_icon)
                //.setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(subtitle)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

my php server file:-

```
$fields = [
            'to'           => '/topics/test2',
            'data' => [
                "image" => "https://example.com/image.png",
                "title" => "aaaaaaa",
                "subtitle" => "bbbbbbb",
                "content" => "ccccc",
                "url" => "https://example.com/news90789/",
                "time" => "dddd",
                "category" => "rrrrrr"
            ]
        ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows only one because of this:

```
notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Change it to this:

```
int num = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
notificationManager.notify(num, notificationBuilder.build());
```

The notification id should be unique for each notification. Now you won't have only one notification as they were overriding each other and that is why when you clicked the notification you only got the first value.

Comment: Thanks, this is working, I am not sure how to show different data as it still showing the data of the first notification received

Comment: @SNos are you recieving `intent.putExtra("image", image);
                intent.putExtra("title", title);..` those data in the activity? It should not show the first. Are you clicking on notification then app opens, then you click on another notification?

Comment: Yes I am receiving `intent.putExtra("image", image); intent.putExtra("title", title);..` in the activity called NewsNotification. I receive the notification, I open the app clicking on it and it shows the first. Now if I click on the second nothing happens. Or if the app is closed and I click on the second notification received, values of the first notification is showing

Comment: in your php server, you are sending the same data? Are you always sending this in the title `"aaaaaaa"`?

Comment: @SNos the data in the server needs to be a variable entered by the user. If it is like this `"aaaaaaa",` or even if you change it to `bbbbb` you will always recieve that

Comment: Ok I have tried this. The notification are showing different title and sub in the notification panel, however when I click on the last one the values of the first is displayin all the time

Answer (score 2):

You need to use different notification id while notifying

```
notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
// should be different.   ^^
```

[**notify (int id, Notification notification)**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification))

> Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification
>   `with the same id has already been posted by your application and has
>   not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

so

```
int id = 0; 
notificationManager.notify(id++, notificationBuilder.build());
// should be different.   ^^
// you can use shared preference to keep track of id 
// so that in future you can cancel it via java code
```

Comment: thank you I have more notifications now. However, the data when I click always shows the first received

Comment: can you check the values of these variables `String image, String title, String subtitle,` make sure they are different , use logs to check value

Comment: You mean different from the data received on both notifications?

Comment: yes, make sure data is different for every notification