# How to show a single notification icon in the status bar for Single notifications

Tags: android, notifications

I want to show every single notification separately and not repeat same notification which is already present on status bar in android.

Here is my code which is giving me multiple notification in one notification actually its updating current notification which I don't want.

```
 private void showNotification(String message) {

            Intent i = new Intent(this,NotificaitonDesign.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           // i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.putExtra("message_send",message_send);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle("Discount Location")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bell_notification)
                    .setSound(sound)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            manager.notify(0,builder.build());
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Firebase Notification open an Activity when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48952935/android-firebase-notification-open-an-activity-when-clicked)

Comment: okay but how can I prevent from duplicate or identical notification?

Comment: I am getting Similar/notification repeatedly how can I stop them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a unique id for each notification

```
manager.notify(unique_id, builder.build());
```

Also, you can cancel a specific notification using it's unique id
You can achieve this using this simple example for generating a 'run-time' static int that will be unique.

```
public class UniqueId {

  private static int id = 0;

  public static int nextId() {
    return id = id++;
  }
}
```

Comment: okay but how can I prevent from duplicate or identical notification?

Comment: I am getting Similar/notification repeatedly how can I stop them ?

Comment: how to check notification is active or not on status bar In android?

Comment: 1) and 2) You need to manage it yourself, if you want new notification use a new id, if you want to update a notification use the same id and consider using PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT in your PendingIntent, depending on what you want to do...

Comment: Let's say you have a chat app, and each conversation has a unique id you can use as a unique notification id. when you post a notification for a specific chat you use this unique id. This way you will update the conversation-specific notification and create a new one for another conversation..

Comment: 3) You can use the getActiveNotifications method: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#getActiveNotifications()